# How to fetch only specific data between dates from MongoDB atlas using PHP?

Tags: php, database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB atlas using PHP.

Error:

> Cannot use object of type MongoDB\Driver\Cursor as an array

Here is my **Code**

```
        $id           = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("3c4052f6-f0ac-11ea-959b-0068ebdc2fd0");
 $filter      = ['_id' => $id];
 $options = [];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://');
$result = $manager->executeQuery('database_name.collection', $query);
foreach ($result as $document) {
    print_r($document);
  }
```

Here is my **MongoDB structure** looks like
[this(Database structure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11NVH.jpg)

How can i fetch specific data from mongodb using php?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. What is your issue exactly ? Does your code generate an error message ? We will have a hard time helping you if we don't know what you need.

Comment: @How can i fetch  specific data from mongodb using php